# Optimization of adaptive filter using AVX instruction set

Tags: optimization, filtering, intel, sse, avx

I am trying to optimize adaptive filtering code using AVX whose filter kernel may be random for every pixels (say 0 to 991).

It's corresponding C code is given below:

```c
/* filter function */
    void filter()
{
  int size = width *height;  // image size
  float w[992][11];          // filter kernel array 
  float x[size + 10], y[size], filterindex[size]; // input , output , filter index 

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
  {
    int l;
    /* pick filter: */
    l = filterindex[i];

    /* apply filter */
    for (k = -5, a = 0.; k <= 5; k++)
        a += x[i+k] * w[l][5+k];
        y[i] = (float)a;
  }
}
```

where

1. `filterindex` is a input buffer which holds filter index (0 to 991) for each pixels [there is no pattern on these index between surrounding pixels]
2. `x` is input and `y` is output
3. `w` is filter kernel of size `w[992][2*N_filt + 1]` where each index is initialized for 992 set

Can any one help me how to optimize above code using AVX? If AVX is not possible then please suggest any other way to optimize having target of 3x.

Comment: Just AVX, or is AVX2 available ?

Comment: I think you're going to be hard-pressed to get a 3x improvement using SIMD in this case. There just isn't very much parallelism to be had; the filter kernels themselves are too short to get much benefit by computing pieces of the convolution in parallel, and the fact that the kernel differs on a per-pixel basis complicates computing multiple pixels in parallel. You may be able to eke out some slight improvements, I think this is a case where moving up a level and searching for algorithmic changes to improve speed is going to be your best bet.

Comment: the second for loop may not work as you expected since the line `y[i] = (float)a;` is outside the loop

Comment: @JasonR: What kind of algorithm changes you are hinting here?

Comment: @Learner: Only the OP can decide that. When optimization of your implementation won't get you to where you need to be performance-wise, you need to take a look at your algorithm to see if a different approach will perform better while still meeting your goals.

Comment: @ Paul R: I have option of till AVX.

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc : Please consider y[i] = (float)a; is inside in inner for loop

Comment: Your code as it is now is not really amenable to SIMD. However, it can benefit from MIMD easily (e.g. with OpenMP). Are you interested in this? Add `#pragma omp parallel for private(k,a)` before your loop over `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every input pixel you can load the 11 filter coefficients in two AVX registers (padding with 5 zeroes in the second one), and load the pixels similarly: _mm256_load_ps.

Multiply and add the values pairwise, giving you 8 sums of 2 products: _mm256_mul_ps, _mm256_fmadd_ps.

Next you need to condense to a single value, using a sequence of horizontal additions, producing sums of 4, 8 and 16 products: _mm_hadd_ps.

Total: 9 instructions per output pixel.

Comment: This approach doesn't give better gain because of below two operation                  1. > To condense to single value                                     2. > Do padding with zero

Comment: What padding do you mean ? Pixel/coefficients or later when condensing ? In the first case, there is no need to explicitly pad if your filter coefficients are stored in a [911][16] array padded with zeroes (that will make extraneous pixels vanish).

Answer (score 1):

Since the weights vary per pixel you may not get a huge speedup trying to filter multiple pixels at once using AVX due to the gather load you'd have to do on the filter weights. An alternative approach which would use coherent loads is to take your inner loop and do 8 of the multiplies in parallel since you're loading pixels from x consecutively in memory and filter weights from w consecutively in memory. Since you have 11 weights this doesn't map ideally to the AVX register width but you should still see a speedup. You can then sum up the results using _mm_hadd_ps. You probably want to unroll the loop over multiple pixels to hide some of the latency of the additions. Alternatively you could try using the _mm_dp_ps dot product instruction to do the multiplies and additions together, it may be faster but the latency is higher so you'll need to unroll the loop more.

This loop is also very parallelizable so it might be worth considering splitting the work across multiple threads.

Comment: @mathnewport : I do have considered using _mm_hadd_ps and _mm_dp_ps as well but got negligible gain. Even unrolling also does not helped us. Considering all the approach we are observing gain of around 1.7x times only. Also currently we are not looking solution using multi-threaded approach.

Comment: It's quite likely you are memory bandwidth limited in that case. Have you done any profiling?

Comment: I have done profiling using rdtsc() and Vtune as well